# Hiding a div when a value is empty

Tags: php, parsing, html, hide

I've got this:

```
if ($image1 !=='') { //Div here }
```

But I'm getting parse errors when I put my div in between the curly brackets. There must be a certain way this needs to be that I'm not doing properly...?

Comment: Show us the full code, and the parse error you are getting.  Without this information we cannot debug properly.  I don't know how you can expect us to without it.

Comment: Although you have got your answer, do you mind improving you question, so that it helps others too. Question in this community are suppose to be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if ($image1 !== '') {
    echo '<div>foo</div>';
}
```

Or you can tell the server to stop parsing PHP when you get to your HTML code and then tell it to start parsing again when you are done:

```
if ($image1 !== '') {
    ?> <div>foo</div> <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ^_^ This worked! I'll accept your answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($image1 !== '') {
    echo '<div>foo</div>';
}
```